# How to implement user registration & authentication in iOS?

Tags: .net, objective-c, ios, authentication

I have a website created in .NET where users are required to register/login to access their data. I have a SQL Serber database in place and the registration/login module is completely functional. What is the best way to implement this in an iOS app?

I'm thinking of using a web service to call the web method for authentication. But then every time I want to retrieve data, I will have to pass the user login and password in the request. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not pass the user login and password every time. Have the user login initially and then create an authentication token, store it on your server, and pass it back to the client and store it in the keychain. Then, you can just pass in the token each time.

Comment: So using a web service and tokens is the best way to implement user authentication & registration? Is there any other alternative? Just curious..

Comment: What would the alternative to a web service be? You need something to connect to, after all. Tokens are a good idea for security reasons. Also that way, you can also keep track of users with saved logins and flush the tokens out if you want users to have to log in again for some reason. As an alternative you can of course use facebook or google authentication. In any case, they will still be passing a token to you that you will be storing.